# does decrementing a NULL pointer lead to undefined behavior?

Tags: c

Decrementing a NULL pointer on my machine still gives a NULL pointer, I wonder if this is well defined.

```c
char *p = NULL;
--p;
```

Comment: Can you show what test you ran to demonstrate that you still have a NULL pointer?

Comment: Gives a null pointer how? Where?

Comment: @user207421. Decrement is an in-place operation

Comment: I don't believe your analysis. Your pointer is not NULL after the decrement.

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer. Given the specific wording "...on my machine still gives a NULL pointer, ...", I feel like further clarification is necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the behavior is undefined.

`--p` is equivalent to `p = p - 1` (except that `p` is only evaluated once, which doesn't matter in this case).

[N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.5.6 paragraph 8, discussing additive operators, says:

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted
>   from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the
>   pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array
>   is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the
>   original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the
>   resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression.
>   [...]
>   If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements
>   of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
>   object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined.

Since your pointer value `p` doesn't point to an element of an array object or one past the last element of an array object, the behavior of `p - 1` is undefined.

(Incidentally, I'd be surprised if your code caused `p` to be a null pointer -- though since the behavior is undefined the language certainly permits it. I can imagine an optimizing compiler ignoring the `--p;` because it knows its behavior is undefined, but I haven't seen that myself. How do you know `p` is null?)

Comment: `Since your pointer value p doesn't point to an element of an array object or one past the last element of an array object, the behavior of p - 1 is undefined.`...just before that paragraph it is also said, `For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an
array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the
type of the object as its element type.`..so, how to address that part?

Comment: @rici how is that? As I see it, NULL is a null-pointer constant, and that is _"An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
`void *`,.."_. So, basically, it's a pointer to `void`, and from 6.3.2.1/P1 - _"....(with an object type other than `void`)...". So, `NULL` is a pointer to an object type - right? What am I missing?

Comment: @sourav 6.2.5/19: "The `void` type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete object type that cannot be completed". In other words, there is no object of type `void`. Moreover, 6.3.2.3/3: "If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function."

Comment: @rici OK, I see, it's the object type that exists, not the object.

Comment: @sourav, for some definition of "exists" :-). In C, at least, types are a figment of the compiler's imagination.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I see with GCC it does not generate a null pointer. Decrementing is just subtracting a number. With underflow the number just wraps around. You can see that here.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
{
    char *p = NULL;
    printf("%zx\n", (uintptr_t)p);    
    --p;
    printf("%zx\n", (uintptr_t)p);
}
```

Output is

```
0
ffffffffffffffff
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/gNzc38RWGSBi9tS3

Comment: That doesn't address whether it's well defined, which is what the OP asked.

Comment: And you should use `%p` to print pointer values: `printf("%p\n", (void*)p);`

Comment: Fair enough. I guess the reasonable behavior is it to work as it does but the spec is flexible enough that on some systems it is allowed not to (a.k.a undefined). Do you have an example of a system where the above code will not produce the above output?

Comment: Sure, the second line can be `ffffffff`. More generally, most systems represent the null pointer as all-bits-zero, but that's not specified by the language. One more thing: `#include "stdio.h"` should be `#include <stdio.h>`, and `int main()` should be `int main(void)`.